# PHP How to scrape content from this specific URL

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler

Can someone please tell me how they would personally get the price of the product from pages like this URL https://www.wayfair.com/The-Childrens-Factory-48-H-x-24-W-Mirror-CF332-132-GBS1086.html

I've been trying for days with no luck.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, I'd say ask them. They have an email address. Especially since you need their agreement to you scraping their site anyway.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: @Robert I'm using the same code Jose posted below. Turns out its not returning a string when I put it into a function and set return $all[$pos]; it returns 1. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-paste next code in a PHP file and run it in your browser :

```
<?php
// ▼ FIRST, GET THE WHOLE HTML FROM THE WEB PAGE.
$all = file_get_contents("https://www.wayfair.com/The-Childrens-Factory-48-H-x-24-W-Mirror-CF332-132-GBS1086.html");
$pos = strpos( $all,"dynamic-sku-price" ); // ◄■■ PRICE TAG.
$pos += 36; // SKIP SOME HTML CHARS.
while ( $all[ $pos ] != chr( 10 ) ) // ◄■■ GET PRICE CHARS UNTIL END OF LINE.
{ echo $all[ $pos ];
  $pos++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Download html string of this page and Use DOM xpath and parse it.

Comment: I've attempted to do this many time but can't get anything. Whenever I try to load the URL via file_get_contents I always get an error